# Format of `{ids}` missing in the api documentation

Tags: feature-request, api, documentation

A problem I stumbled upon is that the format of `{ids}` in the API documentation is unknown. It took a while to figure out that the requested format was `2;3;5` (and I'm not sure this is the only accepted format).

It would be nice if the API documentation could provide the correct format or at least provide some examples. It is possible the site already explains it, but in that case, one can claim that part of the documentation was not that accessible.

It is possible this is the "standard" for lists in a web-API url, but in that case it would be nice that the documentation is more comprehensive for non-experts in web APIs.

Comment: Issues with the API (including the documentation) should really be reported on http://StackApps.com.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No problem, can you move this question?

Comment: I cannot, I'm not a moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mentioned in [the section on batching](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/vectors):

> When passing a vector, sepeate each id with a semicolon. For example, [/users/1;2;3;4;5?site=somesite](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) would fetch users with ids 1 through 5 on somesite.

as well as routes which take `{ids}`-like parameters, i.e. [/answers/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids) (emphasis added):

> {ids} can contain up to 100 **semicolon delimited** ids

Comment: Thanks, I must have overlooked it.